# MacOS VPN client that can handle 2 OpenVPN connections simultaneously

Tags: macos, vpn

On my MacOS laptop I want to use 2 VPN connections simultaneously and route traffic through connection based on hosts. My current client is OpenVPN Connect and it can not establish 2 connections simultaneously

Please advise an alternative. Ideally, I would like to be able to route traffic depending on the hosts it goes to, but I’m not sure that such functionality is included in VPN clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Tunnelblick.app. It works with multiple connections and you can add route example.com to config file for certain connection.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you added some more detail as to how this meets the questioner's needs.